# how to assert in my tests that a Chai assertion will fail (Error vs. AssertionError)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am puzzled by the inheritance relationship of `Error` and `AssertionError` and how that works with `assert.throws`.

In my test code I have:

```
// @flow
...
import {assert} from 'chai';
import {AssertionError}  from 'assertion-error';

describe('foo', function() {
    it('boo', function() {
        assert.throws( ()=>{throw new Error()}
                       , AssertionError); //a 
        assert.throws( ()=>{throw new AssertionError()}
                       , Error);          // b
        assert.throws( ()=>{assert.isTrue(false);}
                       , Error);          // c
        assert.throws( ()=>{assert.isTrue(false);}
                       , AssertionError); // d
    });
});
```

*all* of the above `assert.throws` statements succeed. I was expecting some of them to succeed and some to fail.
Specifically, given that AssertionError has Error as its prototype I was expecting `a` to fail as a stricter type is demanded (`AssertionError`) than that thrown (`Error`). Instead it succeeded along with the rest. What gives?

The packages I am using are:

```
chai@4.1.2
mocha@3.5.3
```

## update

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458047/274677) I confirm that if, instead of:

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import {AssertionError}  from 'assertion-error';
```

… I do:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const AssertionError = require('assertion-error');
```

… then the results are as expected.

Comment: Are you using typescript, babel or anything else to use the import statement ?

Comment: babel-core 6.7.4 with the `es2015` preset in the `.babelrc` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not a Babel user, but I installed it and tried and compiling with the preset mentioned and got the same error, I logged AssertionError and it's not being imported (undefined).

I changed the import statement to :

```
import {assert} from 'chai';
import AssertionError  from 'assertion-error';
```

And it works fine.

The reason is by doing 
`import {AssertionError} from ...` it is actually looking for an exported property of the package 'assertion-error', basically like doing `require('assertion-error').AssertionError`, the AssertionError class is the default export of the assertion-error package.

What's sad though, is that it fails silently, but actually, it makes sense because babel transpiles it to this, so it never checks if the property is present:

```
var _assertionError = require('assertion-error');

_chai.assert.throws(function () {
    throw new Error();
}, _assertionError.AssertionError);
```

Also, this is a bug in `chai` as if the 2nd argument is present, chai should consider it even if it is undefined and throw an AssertionError. It should do something like `if (arguments.length === 2) { // consider the second argument } else { // do not consider it }`. Pull request is on the way.

Comment: Yes, but there's also another Chai weirdness at play here, see also my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458205/274677

Answer (score 1):

I just tried

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const AssertionError = require('assertion-error');

assert.throws(
    () => {
      throw new Error();
    },
    AssertionError
);
```

And it worked as expected... wtf
[image]

Comment: I confirm that I get the exact same behavior. Added update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
import {AssertionError}  from 'assertion-error';
```

… fails silently and `AssertionError` is `undefined`

This, coupled with the fact that the following succeeds:

```
    it('weird', function() {
        assert.throws(()=>{
            throw 1;
        }, undefined);
    });
```

… yielded the observed situation.

Once I changed the import to read:

```
import AssertionError  from 'assertion-error';
```

… the observed situation was the expected one.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, a pull request could definitely be done and I might do it soon. They should check the length of argument of the throws function like that `if (arguments.length === 3) { // consider the last argument } else { // do not consider } ` what they are probably doing is just (`if (nameOfArgument) {} else {}`, so it's just behaving like you didn't pass any argument.